# Error: There was data source access error. Please contact the gateway administrator

Tags: ssas, powerbi-desktop

I publish visual into Power Bi desktop using SSAS multidimensional. I connect the data source gateway (standard gateway) and already connected

[connected gateway picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex2Lb.png)

but when I reload the page I got one more error and the visual is blank (no data)
[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvWVZ.png)

Can someone tell me what is wrong? or did I miss any step?

Comment: Try to reload dataset from WEB by Refresh Now, and check full error output if appear

Comment: Got the same error after refresh it. Where to check the full error? the error shown same as  error picture above